# Fastest way to split a video file into two?

Tags: macos, video

Does anyone know of software for OS X that can quickly split a 2 hour H.264 video file into two 1 hour files? iMovie estimates 2 hours just to import the file. I was hoping for something that could do it quicker.

Comment: Not really an answer for the question you asked, but I've found it's quicker to add clips to iMovie by opening the iMovie project bundle and dragging the clip into the `Media` folder. When next opened, the clip is in the library and can be used, no waiting.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You might also be able to do this using Quicktime X. Open the movie, then choose Edit -> Trim... Trim away the second part of the movie file and do a save as to get the first part in a separate file. Re-open the original file and trim away the first part, save as to get the second part in a separate file.

I've only been able to try it with a 5 minute long movie, which was quick enough, but I'm unsure of how quickly it'll work with a 2 hour movie.

Comment: Beautiful solution, Lizzan. Fast, free, readily available. Thanks.

Comment: @jlpp: Glad I could help! =)

Comment: This is working fine. And for 2 hour movie it takes only 3 minute.

Comment: Even in at the end of 2016, in Sierra, this is still the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: `Edit > Split Clip` is even better. Scrub to position, split clip, delete one of the clips, save. Undo and delete the other clip, save.

Comment: This worked like a charm until trying to Save As... to save separately the second of three clips, which made QuickTime crash. Even reopening QuickTime with a different file now results in an immediate crash on starting the app.

Comment: Unfortunate that this changes the file type to `.mov`

Answer (score 6):

The easiest tool would probably be Quicktime 7 Pro.  I believe it is available on Apple's store for $30.

If you prefer a CLI method, take a look at mp4box.  It has a -split option that does what you're describing.

Answer (score 2):

## Movie Splitter

> Split MPEG-4 movies with ease and speed.

[Movie Splitter](http://miln.eu/moviesplitter/) can split your [H.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) (.mp4) movie into two halves. A multi-gigabyte split typically takes a minute or two. The bulk of the time is spent reading and writing the file.

If an application takes longer than a few minutes, it is likely re-encoding your movie. You do not want this because it risks reducing the quality of your split movie files.

Please note [I wrote Movie Splitter](http://theworklife.com/graham-miln/2014/05/08/making-movie-splitter/) and am likely bias.

[image: Miln Movie Splitter for Mac OS X]

Comment: Why don't you note that your Movie Splitter works ONLY with Canon Hybrid format video?

Comment: Movie Splitter works with `mp4` format, as recognised by [AVFoundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html)/QuickTime on OS X. A well formed MPEG4 movie with chapter markers should work. Complete details about the product, its capabilities, and focus is on: http://miln.eu/moviesplitter/

Comment: Movie Splitter v1.4.0 now works with any AVFoundation supported movie format, including `mov`, `qt`, and `mp4`.

Answer (score 1):

Some other options are:

- [Splitfuse](http://likelysoft.com/splitfuse)
  ($12, free to try)
- [Simple Video Splicer](http://files.chipersoft.com/svs.sit) which looks free, but I havn't tried it. You'll see the link on the right of the [dev's page](http://files.chipersoft.com/svs.sit).

Comment: You know, I never think the answer is going to be buried by top votes, but this is EXACTLY what I needed. It does passthrough of audio and video formats. Can queue up multiple splits. I've been wanting to chop up gigs of video for years and struggled with this. Paying and supporting Splitfuse, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hjsplit.org/

Completely free, completely awesome.

Comment: This splits the file into chunks, but you have to recombine them to be able to watch them. The OP needs to split a video file into two video files.